# How to style ExtJS 4 app with compass without building it first

Tags: extjs, sass, compass-sass, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to style my ExtJS app, that I created with SenchaCmd and I have created a theme and also a custom .scss style in the `appdir/sass/var` folder. However every time I update the styles in either the theme or the app, I have to rebuild the app with sencha app build. When I use `compas watch .` it creates a folder `appdir/stylesheets` which is useless. How can I use `compass watch` without having to rebuild the app every time I make a CSS change?

Cheers:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ExtJS 4.2, you can't use `compass watch` any longer. However, if you don't want to do a full rebuild each time, you can do `sencha ant sass`. Note that this will only work for existing .scss files...if you add any, you will have to do a full app or package build. Once you build, though, you can use `sencha ant sass` again for updates to existing .scss files.

Comment: whats the reason for that i cant use it any longer?

Comment: Because Sencha hates us :)  Seriously, when I watched the theming video and the guy was using `compass watch`, the world seemed so lovely. `sencha ant sass` is so slow by comparison.